# How to read helm chart release namespace and patroni cluster name into a bash file that creates database inside a patroni pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have created a post-install hook for a helm chart, its config is like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  pgsql-setup-post-install.sh: |
    #!/bin/sh
    kubectl wait --for=jsonpath='{.status.PostgresClusterStatus}'=Running postgresql/t1-patroni -n robin-ns --timeout=3600s
    kubectl exec -n robin-ns t1-patroni-0 -- sh -c  "PGPASSWORD=postgres /usr/bin/psql -d postgres -c \"CREATE USER robin CREATEDB PASSWORD 'robin123'\" -p 5432 -U postgres"
    kubectl exec -n robin-ns t1-patroni-0 -- sh -c  "PGPASSWORD=postgres /usr/bin/psql -d postgres -c 'ALTER USER robin with SUPERUSER' -p 5432 -U postgres"
    kubectl exec -n robin-ns t1-patroni-0 -- sh -c  "PGPASSWORD=postgres /usr/bin/psql -d postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE robin_storage owner=robin' -p 5432 -U postgres"
    kubectl exec -n robin-ns t1-patroni-0 -- sh -c  "PGPASSWORD=postgres /usr/bin/psql -d postgres -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext' -p 5432 -U postgres"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pgsql-setup-post-install-sh
  namespace: robin-ns
```

I want to replace the hardcoded namespace robin-ns with release namespace but `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` is not working
Same goes with the hardcoded patroni cluster name

The **t1-patroni** is the name of patroni cluster under the namespace **robin-ns** and **t1** is the name of helm chart release which is been deployed under namespace robin-ns.

How do I read the patroni cluster name i.e **t1-patroni** in this case, which is dynamic and depends on helm release name (here release name is t1) and how to replace robin-ns with the helm release namespace. Also the **exec** should be done on patroni leader pod, so we need to get the leader first.

Comment: what vars you are using in helm, when you say release.namespace not working thn which var there to get values like NS, cluster name ? share your actual helm template if you are trying anything